# Express GET: running Python with Spawn, reading file with fs and sending response give a delayed result

Tags: node.js, express, fs, spawn

I was using `Express` with `GET` to run the following command

```
app.get('/get_temp_hum', function(req, res) {
        var process = spawn('python',["ECIES_decotp.py"]);
        process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
        } )
        process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
        } )
        process.stderr.on('exit', function(code) {
            console.log('Exited with code' + code);
        } )
        fs.readFile('c.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //console.log(data);
                temp_hum_json = data;
            })
        res.send(temp_hum_json);
});
```

And I call the URL of that `GET` so I can have it show the value of `res.send(temp_hum_json)`

But for some reason, the first time I call it, it shows me a blank page instead, and it will only show the result after I call the result again after that. The same thing happens too when I call it with Postman. It happens everytime I boot up my server. Which is problematic because I need the value to be show with consistency so I can put the URL on server. It may have a thing to do with some part being asynchronous command, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Spawning a process and also readFile in NodeJS executed asynchronously that's why.
If you want to get result with consistency you need to use callbacks. When you span a process you can get data from that process in realtime with

```
process.stdout.on("data", data => {
  //do whatever you want with data here
})
```

If the python process gives you a json file and you need to read that file you should read it in exit code 0 that Python process sends after finishing the execution

```
 process.stderr.on('exit', function(code) {
       if(code ===0){
         fs.readFile('c.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.send(data);
                })
        }
      })
```

The final code must be like this:

```
app.get('/get_temp_hum', function(req, res) {
        var process = spawn('python',["ECIES_decotp.py"]);
        process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            // do whatever you want here with stream data from python process 
            console.log(data.toString());
        } )
        process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
        } )
        process.stderr.on('exit', function(code) {
            if(code === 0){
             fs.readFile('c.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send(data);
            })
         } 
        } )
});
```

Comment: I tried following your method. Problem is, it didn't do the file reading after that, because of the Python process didn't return the exit code 0. I was just copying the stderr from the internet. How do I make the Python code return the exit code after it finished its job?

Comment: It's strange, because every process must return a exit code unless your python process is a listener and listeners execute to whenever you send them a SIGTERM or SIGKILL, could you please provide the Python code?